# Android LogCat IntelliJ

Tags: android

When I run my project on Intellij , show  `Consumer closed input channel or an error occured events=0x8`   in LogCat. What is it, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input pipe file descriptor(fd) has been closed by someone.  Either the window has been closed so the client correctly closed the fd, or something in the process is accidentally closing that fd when it shouldn't, or the process crashed and the fd got closed by the kernel. Dbug your program by single stepping using eclipse debugger to figure where the bug is.